# Why do the major node arg parsers use chaining syntax?

Tags: node.js, argv

Both [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js) and [yargs](https://github.com/yargs/yargs) use a chaining syntax that is reminiscent of jQuery.

Is the chaining syntax a historical outcome of the era in which the libraries were created, or is there a functional motivation?

Trying to decide whether to write a wrapper with my preferred syntax or not.

**commander**:

```js
program
  .option('-d, --debug', 'output extra debugging')
  .option('-s, --small', 'small pizza size')
  .option('-p, --pizza-type <type>', 'flavour of pizza');

program.parse(process.argv);
```

**yargs**:

```js
yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
  .command('serve [port]', 'start the server', (yargs) => {
    yargs
      .positional('port', {
        describe: 'port to bind on',
        default: 5000
      })
  }, (argv) => {
    if (argv.verbose) console.info(`start server on :${argv.port}`)
    serve(argv.port)
  })
  .option('verbose', {
    alias: 'v',
    type: 'boolean',
    description: 'Run with verbose logging'
  })
  .argv
```

They could instead, for example, accept one large configuration object, which seems more idiomatic:

```js
parse({
  options: {
    debug: {
      description: 'output extra debugging',
      alias: 'd'
    },
    small: {
      description: 'small pizza size',
      alias: 's'
    },
    ['pizza-type']: {
      description: 'flavour of pizza',
      alias: 'p'
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach has the name `fluent interface` and well-known because it simplifies making calls of a bunch of methods of the same object.
The Martin Fowler mentions this approach earlier then `jQuery` appeared. See [Fluent interface](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html)

For instance look at LINQ in C# as a powerful implementation of a fluent interface principle.